# Generally find any function given its power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I find some function given its power series?
In other words, how do I get $\sin(x)$ FROM(and not the opposite) $x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + ...$?
(I *do not* want to show that it is true by getting the series of $\sin(x)$ and then checking if it is equal to $x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + ...$ !!!)

Comment: You do not *get* it: it is the definition of $\sin x$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the series of the exponential function $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

and notice that your series is equal to $$\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
Now think about $y=i\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ and notice that $\frac{dy}{dx}=iy$. Solving this differential equation yeilds $y=e^{ix}$, which results in [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). Then by subtracting $e^{-ix}$ from $e^{ix}$ and then dividing by $2i$, we can see that $$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$ which is equal to the original series.